# USB key (or sd-card) mount in multiseat enviroment

Tags: linux-mint, usb-storage, multiseat

I have PC with Linux Mint 19.2, with multiseat configuration, specifically two seats seat0 and seat1. Both set to autologin. Everything works except auto-mounting USB key or (sd card). When I mount key on seat0, dialog popups on seat1 asking password. This is wrong, because key is plugged in correct usb hub belonging to seat0. This is really annoying and only work-around is mounting manually as root.

Any help will be appreciated.